# Getting VBA to run correctly if I navigate to the next record in access using the standard navigation in bottom of the form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have 3 textBoxes one for quantity in Stock, the other for the amount I want to Use, and the the last one is for the amount I want to Add to the quantity in Stock.

When I Navigate to the next record using the standard navigation controls in the bottom of the form, Stock Does

[image]

I have tired:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
DoCmd.RefreshRecord
DoEvents
Me.Refresh

End Sub
```

But no luck

Comment: Could you share more information about _what you have, what you're trying to do, and what you've tried so far?_  A screen shot showing your issue might also be helpful.  Check out "[mcve]" as well as "[ask]" and "[help/topics]".

Comment: Saving calculated data, especially aggregate data is usually a bad design. Ideally, should save transaction records of stock received/used then calculate the balance when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Why is the `If IsNull...` line in `Sub Used_AfterUpdate` procedure commented? That should trigger compile error.

Comment: I want to Navigate to the next record using the same form the default navigation panel bellow the form allows me to do this. The problem is that the textboxes are not updating if I navigate. Is it possible to start running the codes from the beginning. Every time I navigate to the next record?